# Как сделать поиск картинки с разным текстом на python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pyautogui

Нужно в игре найти картинку и кликнуть на нее. Это я уже сделал через функцию pyautogui.locateOnScreen, так же пробовал через OpenCV, но там у меня не получилось задать точность и он очень часто ее не находит. Сейчас перешел к другому объекту, там текст в черной рамке, текст разный, бывает из 1, 2 и 3 слов и разной длины. Подскажите как это можно реализовать? Примеры картинок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал размазать текст в фотошопе и искать по такой картинке со сниженной точностью, но либо не находит, либо находит только оригинал, а подходим к другому входу с более длинной или короткой надписью и все, уже не опознает.
P.S. Смысл такой - бежим вторым окном за основным, перемещаясь по крестику на карте, когда пропал крестик - тыкаем на проход рядом, который обозначается только надписью, а подсвечивается только при наведении, не елозить же мышкой по всему экрану, пока не засветится проход.. Ну и там форма отличается, не уверен, что он будет всегда находить, хотя тоже вариант, ток хз как правильно это сделать, чтобы водил мышкой по экрану, пока не засветится проход и нажать на него.. Свечение белым цветом всегда. При наведении мышкой на проход выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще вариант, использовать tensorflow и обучить распознавать разные прямоугольники с текстом, только я не смог разобраться как предварительно обучить сеть и как подключить сеть к распознаванию и будет ли она успевать, хотя тут просто прямоугольник найти, а не сложный объект.. Ну и, наверное, это займет кучу времени, а мне надо до вечера доделать. Еще есть запасной вариант, побегать по всей игре 2-3 часа, наскринить все варианты проходов, но это крайний вариант, если никто не сможет помочь.

ВОТ минимальный код, который не работает:

```
dd = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('poloska2.png', confidence=0.45)
        xdd = dd[0]
        ydd = dd[1]
        pyautogui.moveTo(xdd + 15, ydd + 15)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        time.sleep(5)
```

0.45 параметр, это при котором находит размытый вариант, но если чуть отличается ширина, то уже не находит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, остановите этот поток сознания и приведите следующее: Ваш код в обязательном порядке. Что за игра (Ваша рукотворная или чья-то), что конкретно и зачем Вы хотите сделать. Пока что напрашивается такой ответ: *Нужно в игре найти картинку и кликнуть на неё*... Так найдите и кликните! Вообще не понятно, что конкретно требуется от скрипта.

Comment: Я выше скинул 3 картинки, как пример, нужно находить их и кликать на них. Таких много, более 50-60, каждую заскринить проблематично. Фоны самих локаций везде разные, есть как темные, так и светлые сами по себе, так и день/ночь. Игра Path of Exile. Смысл приводить код, который не работает. Поиск зеленого крестика у меня вышел и корректно работает, а надписи на проходах не находятся, они разной ширины и разный текст в них.

Comment: Делаете эрозию-дилатацию (операция открытия) с прямоугольным структурным элементом. Затем бинаризация по порогу, дальше ищите черные прямоугольники, например, определенной высоты.

Answer (score 0):

Способ сложный но попробовать стоит. Для начала вырезать нужную картинку, а потом обработать её с помощью pytesseract(pytesseract - нейросеть которая распазнаёт текст на фотографиях). Основная проблема в том, что pytesseract довольно сложно установить.